# What does a martian source on firewall's external interface mean?

Tags: ip, firewall, ip-address

I know that a martian source is a packet that the kernel did not expect it from where it come, and is mostly due to a misconfigured host on a internal network. However, what does it mean when it comes from a external network.

I get messages like this:

kernel: [xxx.xxx] martian source foo from bar, on dev ethX
kernel: [xxx.xxx] ll header: 00:19:d1:a7:e5:d5:04:62:73:6d:a8:c6:08:00

where:

foo is my public ip
bar is the source, which is another public ip
ethX is my firewall external interface

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

A martian IP address is one which is not supposed to be routed on the public Internet. It is related to a bogon IP address.